# wpf control listen to manipulation even if there other controls above

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a Grid control with some manipulation listeners attached to it, i would to like to have this listeners reacting to manipulation even if there other controls above it

```
<Grid  ManipulationDelta="sliderTouch" ManipulationCompleted="sliderEnd" ManipulationStarted="sliderStart" IsManipulationEnabled="True" x:Name="marcoPannelGrid" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="548" Margin="50,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="980" Grid.RowSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="525*"/>...
```

and the bit of code doing the manipulation

```
if (e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X > MOVEMENT_THRESH)
            {
                marcoTouch = false;
                e.Complete();
                //doing animations

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Controls cannot react to touch if they're behind something else that receives manipulation - this would cause ambiguous behavior on the manipulation of the other control. If, however, you're talking about your grid not receiving events while nested in a control, you sometime have to set the `Background="Transparent"` Property in WPF in order to receive manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

If the controls that are above it do not require any interactivity (i.e. they do not need to respond to click or mousedown events), then you can always set their 'IsHitTestVisible' property to False, thus making them transparent (in terms of hit testing).